# Doesn't work http request from custom components/services in jHipster application

Tags: angular, jhipster

When I create new components and services in app create by jHipster generator, http requests doesn't work in my components/services.

Sorry if I some skip and make wrong, but in the simple angular app this(http) works fine.

I've created simple example and pushed to this repository
https://github.com/SerhiiTsybulskyi/jhiHttpIssue
See this file: https://github.com/SerhiiTsybulskyi/jhiHttpIssue/blob/master/src/main/webapp/app/test/test.component.ts

What are doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http.get()` returns an `Observable`, if you don't subscribe to it the request is not sent. See the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data)

```
  onClick() {
    this.http.get('management/health').map((res) => res.json()).subscribe();
  }
```